# Powershell Active Directory script to export csv with specific information/attributes

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I need to export some information from active directory.
The current powershell script successfully get all the information it is asking for, but I want to also grab the user attribute "description" or "company."

```
$OUpath = 'OU=OU,DC=DC'
$ExportPath = 'C:\path\users_in_ou7.csv'
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $OUpath | Select-object GivenName, Surname,Name,UserPrincipalName | Export-Csv -NoType $ExportPath
```

When I add either of those to the Select-object portion is turns up blank in my CSV.
For example:

```
Select-object Description, Company, GivenName, Surname, Name, UserPrincipalName
```

Column headers are inserted into the CSV, but the values are blank. These attributes are populated in each of the user properties in AD. I am not sure if I am calling them correctly in my script. Any help would be appreiceiated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `-Properties` parameter of the `Get-ADUser` cmdlet.

From the `Get-ADUser` [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-aduser?view=win10-ps):

> This cmdlet retrieves a default set of user object properties. To retrieve additional properties use the Properties parameter.

> Specify properties for this parameter as a comma-separated list of names. To display all of the attributes that are set on the object, specify * (asterisk).

Answer (score 0):

You add the `-properties *` to the query to extract all attributes.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $OUpath -properties * | Select-object Description,GivenName, Surname,Name,UserPrincipalName | Export-Csv -NoType $ExportPath
```